# Redis cluster authentication error while redirecting to another server in the cluster for storing the value

Tags: authentication, redis, passwords, cluster-computing

I have configured redis cluster with 3 master and 3 slaves on three different servers each consists of master and slave. I have set same password to all 3 masters. While storing a value through redis-cli, it redirects to another server in the cluster and failing as auth error.

[1]:

Can anyone tell me whether I can put password in redis cluster or not and how to overcome the above problem. Thanks in advance.

`enter code here`ex: x.x.x.110:7001 redis-cli> auth password
`enter code here`x.x.x.110:7001 redis-cli> set x 9
`enter code here`x.x.x.110:7001 redis-cli> redirected to x.x.x.111:7001 authentication error
`enter code here`x.x.x.111:7001 redis-cli> 
`enter code here`[https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRxB3.png]

Answer (score 0):

If you are just working with redis-cli, you can auth again when redirect happens

```
127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH username password
127.0.0.1:6379> # doing operation here like get ABC
-> Redirected to slot [12792] located at 127.0.0.2:6379
(error) NOPERM this user has no permissions to run the 'get' command or its subcommand
```

Now you should realize that your redis-cli is already redirected to the new server. Just do the auth again and do the operation

```
127.0.0.2:6379> AUTH username password
127.0.0.2:6379> get ABC
127.0.0.2:6379> "ABC"
```